# How do I align textboxes to the right in Flask?

Tags: html, css, flask

I've built a simple Flask app for a neural network that predicts heart disease. The app is deployed via Heroku and works well, at least for my intention; however, I'm working on the app style and can't figure out how to align the textboxes to the right so they look good. I have tried text-align and a few other attempts, but nothing appears to work correctly. Do I need to add code in CSS and HTML?:

```
HTML:
<table>
<form  method="POST">
{# This hidden_tag is a CSRF security feature. #}
{{form.hidden_tag()}}
<br>

<p>{{form.age.label}}: {{form.age}}<br>
<br>
{{form.sex.label}}: {{form.sex}}<br>      
<br> 
{{form.cp.label}}: {{form.cp}}<br> 
<br>
{{form.trestbps.label}}: {{form.trestbps}}<br> 
<br>
{{form.chol.label}}: {{form.chol}}<br> 
<br>
{{form.fbs.label}}: {{form.fbs}}<br> 
<br>
{{form.restecg.label}}: {{form.restecg}}<br> 
<br>
{{form.thalach.label}}: {{form.thalach}}<br> 
<br>
{{form.exang.label}}: {{form.exang}}<br> 
<br>
{{form.oldpeak.label}}: {{form.oldpeak}}<br> 
<br>
{{form.slope.label}}: {{form.slope}}<br> 
<br>
{{form.ca.label}}: {{form.ca}}<br> 
<br>
{{form.thal.label}}: {{form.thal}}<br> 
<br>
{{form.submit()}}
</p>
</form>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
</table>

CSS:



body{
background-color: lightblue;
background-image: url("https://unsplash.com/wallpapers/nature/sky");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height:160px;
padding-left:280px;
padding-top:50px;
width:470px;
color: #eaeaea;
border-bottom:1px solid #eaeaea;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use the table tag correctly. Add those form fields inside the table. use  and  tags. I think it will resolve your problem.

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>column 1</td>
     <td>column 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

no need to use so much breaks if you use table correctly.